# JAVA: How to use the xerces SAXParser using multiple schemas with identical targetNamespaces

Tags: java, xsd, xerces, saxparser

I have a requirement to perform some validation on an incoming piece of XML using a group of schemas.

All these schemas share the same targetNamespace but are separated into different .xsd files.

My java program is loading each xsd file into an InputSource[] array and passing them into the SAX Parser (SCHEMA_SOURCE property).
However, when calling the XMLReader.parse method, I get the following stack trace:

**
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  When using array of Objects as the value of SCHEMA_SOURCE property , no two Schemas should share the same targetNamespace. 
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.processJAXPSchemaSource(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
**

I need to parse the XML using schemas that share a namespace. Is it possible to do this and avoid the above error?

Any form of help or advice will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. It is enforced by [XML and schema specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cvc-resolve-instance).

An entity or an attribute can only be associated with a single namespace, either the default one which is implicit, either an explicit namespace as prefix.

An advice: if your XML input is well-formed but cannot be validated because no namespaces are declared but you have an idea how to implement a logic that can *guess* what the namespace is for each node based on its context like its previous node or its parent node. You may create a pre-processor:

- parse the XML input nodes as DOM (or even with a SAXParser) without schema validation
- apply such a logic and pre-pend entities and/or attributes with *guessed* namespaces
- output again as XML; in that step, you can optionally use a pretty formatter for debug purpose
- now inject that output into your existing parser with schema validation